# Should I send email expressing my gratitude to professors who provided me with letters of recommendation?

Tags: masters, professorship, recommendation-letter

I have asked for LORs from two professors that I haven't cooperated in the past and they were happy to provide them. Now, I've been admitted in the MSc program I was interested in. Should I write an email to them, in order to express my gratitude because of their help in earning this admission?

Comment: Politeness is always appreciated.

Comment: As someone here states time and again, most questions come up from overthinking the issue. The answer by DMlash is good, worst case scenario is if your email ends up in the spam. Otherwise expect the profs to be happy that their efforts turned out to be fruitful.

Answer (score 12):

I think a short, cordial email informing the letter writers of your admittance and thanking them for their help and contribution to such an outcome is absolutely appropriate.